# How to filter all data in AngularJs with select box?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a select box, that I am filtering table. I want that when I select "All" I will see all the data without filter.

This is the select:

```
<select ng-options="o.id as o.name  for o in cities"
    class="form-control"
    name="cities"
ng-model="citiesFilter">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

Here is the full example: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odedtaizi/81t441a6/9/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method shown in the other answer.Or you can achieve the same using `ng-options`.Add the first option also in the `$scope.cities` .The set the default model value.

A sample demo

```js
app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.citiesFilter = '';
  $scope.cities = [{
      "id": '',
      "name": "All"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tel-Aviv"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Haifa"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Eilat"
    },
  ];

  $scope.labels = ["fullname",
    "id_number",
    "phone",
    "email",
    "city"
  ];

  $scope.customers = [{
      "fullname": "Freddie Mercury",
      "id_number": "123456789",
      "phone": "054874874",
      "email": "fred@gmail.com",
      "city": "3"
    },
    {
      "fullname": "Jim Morrison",
      "id_number": "123456789",
      "phone": "054874874",
      "email": "jim@gmail.com",
      "city": "2"
    },
    {
      "fullname": "David Bowie",
      "id_number": "123456789",
      "phone": "054874874",
      "email": "dave@gmail.com",
      "city": "1"
    },
    {
      "fullname": "Prince",
      "id_number": "123456789",
      "phone": "054874874",
      "email": "prince@gmail.com",
      "city": "1"
    }
  ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <select ng-options="o.id as o.name  for o in cities" class="form-control" name="cities" ng-model="citiesFilter">
  </select>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>

        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th ng-repeat="(key,label) in labels" sortable="key">

            {{ label }}
          </th>

        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : {city:citiesFilter}">
          <td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.fullname }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.id_number }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.phone }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.email }}</td>
          <td>{{( cities | filter: {id:cust.city})[0].name }}</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have hid the snippet so that emphasis remains on the explanation and answer looks concise. If you do not want it, you can rollback the commit, but in that case, please use `Tidy` button in editor to indent the code

Answer (score 0):

working code https://jsfiddle.net/dineshu07/uLavay1c/

Use `filter : {city:citiesFilter|| undefined}` to show all

```
<tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter : {city:citiesFilter|| undefined}" >
          <td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.fullname }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.id_number }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.phone }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.email }}</td>

        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom filter function for special handling. This way you have more control and you can add any condition that is required.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/81t441a6/10/)

```js
$scope.myFilter = function(city) {
  return function(cust) {
    return !city || +cust.city === +city
  }
}
```

```html
<tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: myFilter(citiesFilter)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just modified your filter condition to 
`"ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter :(!!citiesFilter || undefined) && {city:citiesFilter}""`

Because,if the filter expression returned undefined, then the filter would not apply

```js
app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
 
   $scope.cities = [
    {"id":1, "name": "Tel-Aviv"},
    {"id":2,  "name": "Haifa"},
    {"id":3,  "name": "Eilat"},
    ];
    
     $scope.labels =  ["fullname",
         "id_number",
         "phone",
         "email",
              "city"];

 $scope.customers = [
      {
       "fullname" : "Freddie Mercury",
       "id_number" : "123456789",
       "phone" : "054874874",
       "email" : "fred@gmail.com",
              "city" : "3"
      },
      {
       "fullname" : "Jim Morrison",
       "id_number" : "123456789",
       "phone" : "054874874",
       "email" : "jim@gmail.com",
              "city" : "2"
      },
      {
       "fullname" : "David Bowie",
       "id_number" : "123456789",
       "phone" : "054874874",
       "email" : "dave@gmail.com",
              "city" : "1"
      },
      {
       "fullname" : "Prince",
       "id_number" : "123456789",
       "phone" : "054874874",
       "email" : "prince@gmail.com",
              "city" : "1"
      }
      ];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
   <select ng-options="o.id as o.name  for o in cities"
   class="form-control"
   name="cities"
  ng-model="citiesFilter">
   <option value="">All</option>
  </select>

    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" >
      <thead>

        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th ng-repeat="(key,label) in labels"  sortable="key">
           
    {{ label }}
          </th>
         
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
       <tr ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter :(!!citiesFilter || undefined) && {city:citiesFilter}" >
          <td>{{ $index +1 }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.fullname }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.id_number }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.phone }}</td>
          <td>{{ cust.email }}</td>
          <td>{{( cities | filter: {id:cust.city})[0].name }}</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps